# Please burninate speed tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

[speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/speed) has the perfect quality of a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

- can’t work as the only tag on a question (I see [speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/speed) on network, bootup, video playback & so on)
- means different things to different people (is it about speeding up? Or once fast system slowed down to a crawl?)

So please [burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/133693) the tag.

[image]

Comment: In many cases where the [tag:speed] tag is used, probably the [tag:performance] tag would be better as it's more widely used. Perhaps it'd be a good idea to edit the tag excerpt to indicate it's best used in conjunction with another tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Comment: retagging isn't a problem - I'd have done that a long ago. The whole point of a burn-a-tag request is to avoid bumping topic to front page.

Comment: @Sathya My bad. Terminology derp on my part. Answer updated. :)

Comment: thank you, Anna!

Comment: @AnnaLear Yay! :)